Smooth Scroll Between Sections on Mouse Wheel in Angular 17
I have an Angular 17 application with several sections, and I want to implement smooth scrolling between these sections when the user scrolls the mouse wheel. Specifically, I want the following behavior:

Each section should scroll into view smoothly when the user scrolls the mouse wheel.
Scrolling should be disabled while the smooth scroll is happening to avoid interrupting it.
Each section is an individual component and it has a height of 100vh

Here is my current HTML structure:
<app-menu ></app-menu>
<app-home id="home"></app-home>
<app-about id="about"></app-about>
<app-skills id="skills"></app-skills>
<app-contact id="contact"></app-contact>

How can I achieve this in Angular 17?
What I have tried:
I have implemented the following code in my main component to handle the scrolling logic:
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  sections: string[] = ['home', 'about', 'skills', 'contact'];
  currentSectionIndex = 0;
  isScrolling = false;

  @HostListener('window:wheel', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
    if (this.isScrolling) return;

    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      this.nextSection();
    } else {
      this.previousSection();
    }
  }

  nextSection() {
    if (this.currentSectionIndex < this.sections.length - 1) {
      this.currentSectionIndex++;
      this.scrollToSection(this.sections[this.currentSectionIndex]);
    }
  }

  previousSection() {
    if (this.currentSectionIndex > 0) {
      this.currentSectionIndex--;
      this.scrollToSection(this.sections[this.currentSectionIndex]);
    }
  }

  scrollToSection(sectionId: string) {
    this.isScrolling = true;
    const element = document.getElementById(sectionId);
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isScrolling = false;
      }, 1000); // Adjust time to match scroll duration
    }
  }
}

Thank you for your help!


Here is a solution using intersection observer. The observer will trigger when the element is visible on the view port for a threshold of 0.1 to 0.2 (feel free to tune this). This creates the desired result.
Then I trigger the method window.scrollTo(...) which will create the scroll logic, then finally we can use click event on the navbar to scroll to the menu.
scrollTo(id: string) {
  document.getElementById(id)!.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  HostBinding,
  HostListener,
  Input,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dummy',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [`:host {height:100vh; display: block;width:100vw;}`],
  template: `
    <div></div>
  `,
})
export class Dummy {
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor')
  @Input()
  color = 'red';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [
    `:host {
    position: fixed;
    width:100vw;
    height:55px;
    background-color: magenta;
  }`,
  ],
  template: `
    <a (click)="scrollTo('home')">home</a> |
    <a (click)="scrollTo('about')">about</a> |
    <a (click)="scrollTo('skills')">skills</a> |
    <a (click)="scrollTo('contact')">contact</a>
  `,
})
export class Navbar {
  scrollTo(id: string) {
    document.getElementById(id)!.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <app-navbar/>
    <app-dummy id="home" color="red"></app-dummy>
    <app-dummy id="about" color="green"></app-dummy>
    <app-dummy id="skills" color="purple"></app-dummy>
    <app-dummy id="contact" color="yellow"></app-dummy>
  `,
  imports: [Dummy, Navbar],
})
export class App {
  sections: string[] = ['home', 'about', 'skills', 'contact'];
  currentSectionIndex = 0;
  lastScrolled = '';
  isScrolling = false;
  sections1 = [];
  activeSection: any;
  @HostListener('window:wheel', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
    // console.log(event.deltaY, this.isScrolling);
    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // if (this.isScrolling) return;
    // if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    //   this.nextSection();
    // } else {
    //   this.previousSection();
    // }
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => e.preventDefault(), {
      passive: false,
    });
    this.sections1 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('app-dummy'));
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry, index: number) => {
          const body: HTMLBodyElement = document.querySelector(
            'body'
          ) as HTMLBodyElement;
          console.log(entry.target.id, this.activeSection);
          if (
            entry.isIntersecting &&
            entry.intersectionRatio > 0.1 &&
            entry.intersectionRatio < 0.2 &&
            entry.target.id !== this.activeSection
          ) {
            console.log('apply', entry, entry.target);
            //change active link
            this.activeSection = entry.target.id;
            // body.classList.add('no-scroll');
            const endScroll = Math.round(
              entry.target.getBoundingClientRect().top +
                document.documentElement.scrollTop
            );
            console.log(0, endScroll);
            window.scroll(0, endScroll);
          }
        });
      },
      { threshold: [0.1] }
    );

    this.sections1.forEach((section: any) => observer.observe(section));
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
